# Passing String Parameter into My Socket.io-enabled Angular 2 Component

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, socket.io

I am in the process of moving from using http to using socket.io to bring data into to my Angular 2 app. In the example I'd like help with I am using a private version of the api.service in my component constructor. All I need to do now is call the "get" function that's defined in the api.service (already set up to use socket.io). This is what the "get" function from the api.service looks like:

```
   public get(req: string, options: any, callback: IRequestCallback) {
          // go get stuff
    }
```

Now in my component I had been using an http get function that looked like this:

```
 getByCategory() {
     return this._http.get(this._url)
         .map((response:Response) => response.json())
         .catch(this._errorsHandler);
 }
```

Now I am change this to use the socket.io function from my api.service instead. As you can see in my code at the top, the socket "get" call from the api.service is asking for 3 parameters (a string, options, and a callback). I tried this:

```
getByCategory() {
    return this.__socket.get(this._url, this.args, function(data) {
    });
}
```

... but now I realize the URL is already being provided in the api.service. So what's stumping me, as silly as this may sound, is what I can pass as the first parameter. I tried passing in an empty string as the first parameter, but that errored out. What string could I pass here, instead of the url? Or is there some other way around this?

Answer (score 0):

First, I've had no issues with the Http module, so I'm curious why you made the switch (not that I know all of the use cases!)

That being said, it sounds like it really depends on how socket.io is handling the underlying code -- optional parameters in Typescript ("optional") normally expect `undefined` as a placeholder, so you could try passing `undefined` in this case.

Comment: Thanks, I will try this. We made the switch to sockets because we have a lot of back and forth, real-time updating going on between client and server, and from multiple users at the same time.

Comment: Gotcha!  I hope it works!  I cannot be sure, as I don't know what the function is doing under the hood, but that's your best bet.

Comment: Trying "undefined" is a good idea. I sometimes forget that "undefined" is not an error, but a valid property.